# How to read parameters from a file when inside a class?

Tags: python, class, file-io, parameters

Suppose I have a Python class like this:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self): 
    self.alive = True
    self.name = 'Alice'
    self.age = 20
```

How can I read parameters from an external file inside this class? I imagine it could be something like the following pseudocode:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, filename): 
    self.alive = True                    # same for all persons
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
      self.name = f.somehow_read_name    # different for all persons
      self.age = f.somehow_read_age
```

such that I can do:

```
alice = Person('alice.txt')
bob = Person('bob.txt')
```

I'd like the external `'alice.txt'` file to be human-readable, so maybe something like this:

```
name = 'Alice' # Name of the person
age  = 20      # Age of the person
### OR ###
{
name : 'Alice', # Name of the person
age  : 20       # Age of the person
}
### OR ###
self.name = 'Alice'
self.age  = 20
```

where the order of the parameters is **not** important.
Until now, I've been doing this:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
  parameters = f.readlines()
  self.name = parameters[8]
```

This is obviously very tedious to maintain when something changes inside the 'alice.txt' file.

Comment: You can use yaml or ini for the human-readable format. Or roll your own. Otherwise your scheme is a good one. Confuse could also be used (any config parser really) - https://confuse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html We've just had to do exactly this ourselves for completely different reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution creates a parser for the human-readable file

**Code**

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, filenm): 
        self.alive = True
        # Get attributes as dictionary
        d = get_attributes_from_file(filenm)

        # Set attributes from dictionary
        for k, v in d.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    def __str__(self):
        # Atributes of object as string (to allow printing of object)
        return str(self.__dict__)
        
def get_attributes_from_file(filenm):
    '''
        Parses attribute file
            returns dictionary of attributes
    '''
    
    
    with open(filenm, 'r') as f:
        # Read file contents
        s = f.read()

        # remove comments
        s = ' '.join(x.split('#')[0] for x in s.splitlines())   
        
        # Convert to dictionary
        # uses comma as delimiter
        d = dict([
                    (term.split(':')[0].strip(), term.split(':')[1].strip("' "))
                    for term in s.strip("{}").split(',')
                ])
    
    return d
```

**Usage**

```
tom = Person('tom.txt')
dick = Person('dick.txt')
mary = Person('mary.txt')
phyllis = Person('phyllis.txt')

print(tom)  # output: {'alive': True, 'name': 'tom', 'age': '20'}
print(dick) # outptu: {'alive': True, 'name': 'dick', 'age': '25'}
print(mary) # {'alive': True, 'name': 'mary', 'age': '35', 'gender': 'female'}
print(phyllis) # Output: {'alive': True, 'name': 'phyllis', 'age': '35', 'gender': 'female', 'sibling': 'tom'}
```

**Files**

tom.txt:

```
name: tom,            # comment such as this are ignored
age: 20               # age
```

dick.txt

```
name: dick,
age: 25
```

mary.txt

```
name: 'mary',       # attributes can be with or without quotes
age: 35,
gender: female     # can have extra attributes
```

phyllis.txt (shows comment only line and blank line)

```
name: 'phyllis',
age: 35,   # age in years

gender: female,
#relatives 
sibling: 'tom'
```

Comment: Can your code deal with a comment-only line in e.g. `tom.txt`?

Comment: @ersbygre1 -- yes, as shown with Phyllis example I added.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have two ways:

First, using pickle to store your python data in it and retrieve. Use this link for more info https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html .

Second you can use specific file format to store and retrieve your data such as CSV, JSON , excel and etc... .

Comment: >> two ways....!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a nice way. I tried to do `from alice import *` inside the class, which did not work (because of the `*`). However, as long as the external file is called `***.py` and I import it inside the class like this:

```
import alice # if the file is 'alice.py'
```

then I can access the variables defined in that file via `alice.name`, etc. and do the following:

```
import alice
self.name = alice.name
self.age  = alce.age
```

Comment: I would strongly disadvise using this approach in a real project. If at any point somebody else is able to upload or change the file alice, then when you run `import alice`, you will be running all the code inside that file. This leaves you open for many security vulnerabilities. 
You might argue that so far you trust everybody using your software, but that might change in the future, leaving this a problem waiting to happen.